# this code doesn't work in IE7 could anyone help me?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7

```
$("#menu ul li").click(function(){
var colorBorder = $(this).parent("ul").find("li:hover").css("border-bottom-color");
alert(colorBorder)
});
```

it works in chrome, opera, firefox, safari, ie9, ie8 but doesn't work in IE7, why??
i think is "li:hover".

http://jsfiddle.net/58sqR/3/

Comment: `.find("li:hover")` .. ?

Comment: yes i get the border-color when li is :hover

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

To me, it looks like

```
$(this).parent("ul").find("li:hover")
```

will return the same element as

```
$(this)
```

Since clicking a `li` also means hovering over it. Have you tried just using

```
var colorBorder = $(this).css("border-bottom-color");
```

Comment: +1, I'm surprised the `li:hover` selector works in all those browsers. Also the CSS `:hover` pseudo-class should not be expected to work for anything else but `<a>` elements.

Comment: var colorBorder = $(this).css("border-bottom-color");

it hasn't border-bottom-color :S